# Return number from a Dataset after calling a SELECT COUNT(*) query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) From Employees
```

I execute the query and have this:

```
    public static int GetNumJobs()
{
    clsJobPosting JobPosting = new clsJobPosting();
    DataSet dsJobs = JobPosting.GetNumRows();
    DataTable dtJobs = dsJobs.Tables[0];
    return Convert.ToInt32(dtJobs.Rows[0]);
}
```

GetNumRows() returns the dataset, I want to return the number of rows from this query, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing this

```
return Convert.ToInt32(dtJobs.Rows[0]);
```

to this

```
return Convert.ToInt32(dtJobs.Rows[0][0]);
```

Also, why are you returning a `DataSet` from `JobPosting.GetNumRows()`? You should return an `int` there so you don't have to repeat the same logic all over your code.

Comment: He is returning an int. It should be a scalar return from his database though, because a DataSet has WAY too much overhead for what he's trying to do.

Comment: That's what I was suggesting, I know the current method is returning an int, I was curious about the DAO method.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `dtJobs.Rows["columnName"];` where columnName is the name of the column returned from the stored procedure.

Just a few code suggestions as well:

1. It's also a little misleading that the method is named `GetNumRows()` but you are returning a `DataSet`. Perhaps make it more readable by saying `GetJobs` or something to that extent.
2. You don't need to prefix your class names with `cls`. The VS IDE will take care of giving you all the necessary information in a number of ways.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a name for the column in the stored procedure:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) ItemCount FROM Employees
```

On a side note, you really shouldn't use COUNT(*). Just use the primary key column, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(ItemID) ItemCount FROM Employees
```

And instead of populating this into a DataSet and grabbing the row, you should use scalar execution. There is way to much overhead filling a dataset for a single value return.

And in your code:

```
return dtJobs.Rows[0].Field<int>("ItemCount");
```